# Unable to shift menu buttons to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a following code:

https://jsfiddle.net/fcx0wkq3/1/

When the result window is expanded, you can see the menu buttons on the left. I want to be able to change the position of these menu buttons and bring them more into the centre or towards the right. When I make the following changes to the `<ul>`

```
<ul style="left:30%">
```

the result becomes like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/70fbsL75/

Here you can see that the buttons are all skewed. What is the solution to solve this problem.

Comment: do you want the menu centered?

Comment: I don't think anyone has understood what I was trying to state here. I do want the menu centered, but the collapsed menu (that which will show on the mobile) to remain the same. I don't want the text in that menu to be aligned to the center or right like it is being over here: https://jsfiddle.net/70fbsL75/

Is there a difference in the javascript or the #cssmenu that can make up for this?

Comment: Updated my answer - let me know if that still doesn't work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove your #cssmenu ul class from the grouped classes and add

```
#cssmenu ul {
margin: 0 0 0 30%; //Or whatever margins you need
}
```

You can position your nav ul. You need to target the #cssmenu and ul to make your javascript render correctly.

You then need to remove the margins & padding in your media query css (around line 196 of your fiddle) to reset the view on mobile devices.

```
#cssmenu ul {
width: 100%;
display: none;
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;       
}
```

Don't forget to remove your inline styling also when using this

```
<ul style="left:30%">
```

should just be

```
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the percentage then.
Try:

```
<ul style="left:50%">
```

This will move it 50% over from the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a padding-left to the li-elements.

```
    padding-left:40px;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fcx0wkq3/2/

or you can change the alignment of the text with

```
  text-align: right;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fcx0wkq3/3/

Answer (score 0):

Add a div wrapping your `<div id="cssmenu"></div>` with a `class` of `container` and append your CSS with the following

```
.container {
    background: #323232;
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the padding of your anchor OR your li element (first row of example)

```
padding-left: 120px;
```

Or you can set the text align of your li to center

```
text-align: center
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center it then you can just set the `li` elements to `display: inline-block` and then on the parent set `text-align: center`.

Then to get rid of the little margin you can just set the `font-size: 0` on the parent (read more about the inline-block problem [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)).

So you will add this:

```
#cssmenu ul {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

And change this:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block; /* this was float before */
}
```

And this will center it, view a [**demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/70fbsL75/1/).

Comment: This is the what the OP asked. Perfect